# Proof of $\sup\{ (n!)^{(\frac{1}{n})}| n ∈ N\} = +∞?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

How do I prove if $\sup\{ (n!)^{1/n} | n \in\Bbb N\} = +\infty$?

I don't know how to properly explain it

Comment: Do you know Stirling's formula?

Comment: No. I'd like it to be explained simply

Comment: OK, what have you tried?  What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: So I tried to connect somehow fact that supremum of N is +∞ and that the (n!)^(1/n) doesn't have the limit. But I don't really know how to connect both

Comment: How do you know $(n!)^{1/n}$ doesn't have a limit?

Comment: I only assume that it doesn't. And that's why I have trouble with proofing that the supremum of it equals +∞.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: suppose for simplicity that $n$ is even.  Then
$$n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdots \frac{n}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) \cdots n \ge \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right) \cdots n > \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{n/2}.$$
What can you conclude about $(n!)^{1/n}$?

Comment: That's a nice one=)

Comment: That (n!)^1/n > √(n/2)?

Comment: I'm really beginner at this kind of things and I don't know how to think about things like this (supremum)

Comment: Right, so if $((n!)^{1/n})_{n=1}^\infty$ had a finite supremum $L$, then every $\sqrt{n/2}$ for $n$ even would also be less than $L$...

Comment: But on the fact that supremum of N=+∞ we know that the sup of (n1)^1/n must be higher that the sup of √n/2 and that is still +∞?

Comment: Correct, that argument also works.  (Though be careful with "higher": in general, even if $a_n < b_n$ for all $n$, all you can conclude is that $\sup_n a_n \le \sup_n b_n$.)

Comment: Something more. It may be obvious, but how do we know that (n/2+1)⋅..⋅n>(n/2)^(n/2)?

Comment: Because each term in the product is greater than $n/2$, and there are $n/2$ terms in the product.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

For $k=1,2...n$ we have that $(k-1)(n-k) \geq 0.$

Thus $(n-k+1)k \geq n$

$$n \cdot 1 \geq n$$ $$(n-1) \cdot 2 \geq n$$ $$(n-2) \cdot 3 \geq n$$ $$.$$ $$.$$ $$.$$ $$.$$ $$.$$ $$2 \cdot (n-1) \geq n$$ $$1 \cdot n \geq n$$

Multiplying all the inequalities we have that $(n!)^2 \geq n^n$

Continue it from here..

Comment: So we get that (n!)^1/n ≥ √n and if √n has infinite supremum, (n!)^1/n has too?

Comment: @ctrlz...Yes...and indeed $\sqrt{n}$ has infinite supremum..it is not a bounded sequence.

Comment: I don't have to prove that √n has infinite supremum? We can base is on a fact that supℕ=infinite?

Comment: @ctrlz...if you want a practise you can prove it..it is not difficult at all..

Comment: I have already found a prove of it, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From
$(1+1/n)^n$
being a bounded increasing sequence
with limit
traditionally called
$e$,
you can show
by induction that
$n! > (n/e)^n$
so that
$(n!)^{1/n} > n/e$.

Actually,
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}
=\dfrac1{e}
$.

Comment: I saw your method earlier. I tried to avoid it, because I haven't learned yet about (1+1/n)^n